# Alter table in Aws Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I've data in s3 and its respective table schema is in aws glue catalog. I write data into table using table name in my spark job.

Now I want to add new column in table, So before running my spark job, If I just alter table and add column, will it update table schema in glue catalog too and spark would be able to write as expected ?

My second thought is just to drop table, and while writing with spark job, it will create table at run time with new column added. Will it create any issue with the existing partitions in S3 or something else ?

Please share your thoughts. what's a correct way of doing it ?

Thanks